# using mingw to cross-compile an opengl app for windows

Tags: opengl, mingw, cross-compiling

heya, i am running linux (ubuntu),

I am having some trouble with this. i've tried downloading glut32.dll and sticking it in mingw's lib/ directory and also setting up the appropriate headers in include/, however - although the compile is fine - the linker has a serious problem looking up the symbols.

how do i go about doing this? how do i build an opengl app for windows using mingw?

thanks,

Comment: I tried doing this as well a couple months ago for my graphics class. I tried everything thing I could think of, but could never solve the linker issues. I ended up just compiling it with Microsoft's compiler and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Windows world, to link something to a DLL you need an "import library".  You can think of these as static libs with stub functions that expose the DLL's symbols.  You need to look for libglut32.a.

If you can't find that, there might even be a Visual C++ to mingw import library conversion tool somewhere on the Internets...  (It's been a while since I needed things like this, so maybe I just dreamed that part up.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you don't even need GLUT, it's already there, only need to link against libopengl32.a, which will link the executable to native opengl32.dll on the system.

```
typedef struct RENDER_SURFACE {
    void (*redraw)(struct RENDER_SURFACE*);
    HWND hWnd;
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    HDC hdc;
    HGLRC hrc;
    int width;
    int height;
    int pix_fmt;
    float light_position[4];
    float light_ambient[4];
    float light_diffuse[4];
    float light_specular[4];
    float light_shininess;
} RENDER_SURFACE;

static LRESULT AppProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    RENDER_SURFACE* rs = (RENDER_SURFACE*)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    if (uMsg == WM_CREATE)
    {
        RECT rc;
        PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd;
        rs = (RENDER_SURFACE*)((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->lpCreateParams;
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)rs);
        rs->hWnd = hWnd;
        rs->hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
        rs->width = rc.right-rc.left;
        rs->height = rc.bottom-rc.top;
        memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(pfd));
        pfd.nSize = sizeof(pfd);
        pfd.nVersion = 1;
        pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL;
        pfd.cColorBits = 24;
        pfd.cDepthBits = 32;
        rs->pix_fmt = ChoosePixelFormat(rs->hdc, &pfd); 
        if (!rs->pix_fmt)
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd, "ChoosePixelFormat FAILED!", "Fatal Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            return -1;
        }
        SetPixelFormat(rs->hdc, rs->pix_fmt, &pfd);
        rs->hrc = wglCreateContext(rs->hdc);
        wglMakeCurrent(rs->hdc, rs->hrc);
        /* SwapBuffers(rs->hdc); */
        return 0;
    }
    else if (uMsg == WM_PAINT)
    {
        /* other stuffs */
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```